# unmet dependencies and broken count>0 problem

Tags: apt, dependencies, package-management

I tried installing fbreader, following all the steps, but ended up with unmet dependencies, i also think a file is referenced in two locations at once and hence killing it..

any ideas how I can fix it? i've done alot of research and tried:

```
simon@simon-Studio-1558:~$ sudo apt-get -f install  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
Correcting dependencies... Done  
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:  
  dkms patch  
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.  
The following extra packages will be installed:  
  libzlcore0.12  
The following NEW packages will be installed:  
  libzlcore0.12  
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.  
6 not fully installed or removed.  
Need to get 0 B/270 kB of archives.  
After this operation, 811 kB of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y  
(Reading database ... 179860 files and directories currently installed.)  
Unpacking libzlcore0.12 (from .../libzlcore0.12_0.12.10dfsg-4_i386.deb) ...  
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libzlcore0.12_0.12.10dfsg-4_i386.deb (--unpack):  
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libzlcore.so.0.12.10', which is also in package libzlcore 0.12.10-1  
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already  
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
/var/cache/apt/archives/libzlcore0.12_0.12.10dfsg-4_i386.deb  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

sorry for the formatting, but it basically isn't liking:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libzlcore0.12_0.12.10dfsg-4_i386.deb (--unpack):  
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libzlcore.so.0.12.10', which is also in package libzlcore 0.12.10-1
```

Any ideas? Also I don't care about keeping the program, but the error is stopping

```
sudo apt-get remove fbreader
```

from working too.

Answer (score 2):

I had quite a similar error message:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.8.0~rc1-0precise0~ppa_amd64.deb (--unpack): 
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/file-xmc', which is also in package gimp-plugin-registry 3.5.4-1 dpkg-deb: 
error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

And `apt-get` stopped working for me as well, wouldn't do anything useful anymore. Same for the software center, however synaptic would still work (at least kind of) and I could deinstall the conflicting package `gimp-plugin-registry 3.5.4-1` with it.

So you might give it a shot with Synaptic, although I wouldn't know how to get it unto your system when apt-get isn't working and you haven't already installed it.

UPDATE: I think I have a hunch about a more generic approach to solving this issue. You could try `dpkg - P libzlcore 0.12.10-1`, but as I already solved my issue I can't test it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I seem that your  drive is full and has no free space. Try moving some unwanted files like  to another partition and ,make some free space. 
Type

> sudo apt-get install --fix-broken